# Kafka Streams SSL Auth without a key store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to provide ca-cert / key / pem directly to a kafka streams client without a key / trust store?

I am setting up SSL on the cluster, and my ecosystem has a mixture of apps, some of which use librdkafka
https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SSL-with-librdkafka
and some of which use the Java Kafka streams API -

The librdkafka apps can take certs directly like so (see link above)

```
security.protocol=ssl
ssl.ca.location=ca-cert
ssl.certificate.location=client_client.pem
ssl.key.location=client_client.key
ssl.key.password=password
```

Every example I see for kafka streams apps has a key / trust store.
looking in the `org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs` at the available configs,
http://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka//0.11.0.3/javadoc/constant-values.html#org.apache.kafka.common.config.SslConfigs.SSL_PROVIDER_DOC
I don't see any configs that would let me do this, but I also know not all available configs are pre-defined, and sometimes you can set values with a string definition.

I'd like to do this without a store, and provide the data directly, so all the the apps are working in a similar fashion, is it possible to do this with a kafka streams app?

Thank You

Comment: We had a similar setup in our organization, So we created jks files in our CI/CD pipeline, hope u can do the same

Comment: @Parmod thanks for your feedback, thats basically the route we are going down.  Seems there is no way to avoid this